# Unable to start up mongod due to missing featureCompatibilityVersion document. Docker issue

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a dockerized service, It consists in a server with an API REST and a mongoDB storage system.

First of all I have these two images of docker hub:

- mongo:3.6.0
- node:alpine

I'm trying to create a backup with a snapshot from my server. When I performed the restoration and I started to wake up the services, mongoDB crashed. This is the error log:

```
mongo_1  | 2018-01-09T18:50:17.770+0000 F STORAGE  
[initandlisten] Unable to start up mongod due to missing featureCompatibilityVersion document.

mongo_1  | 2018-01-09T18:50:17.774+0000 F STORAGE  
[initandlisten] Please run with --repair to restore the document.

mongo_1  | 2018-01-09T18:50:17.774+0000 F -       
 [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40652 at src/mongo/db/db.cpp 660

mongo_1  | 2018-01-09T18:50:17.775+0000 F -        [initandlisten]
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine


RUN mkdir /CSCFUTSAL
WORKDIR /CSCFUTSAL


COPY package.json /CSCFUTSAL

RUN cd /CSCFUTSAL

RUN npm install

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

COPY . /CSCFUTSAL

RUN ng build --prod

EXPOSE 80
```

And my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
 mongo:
  image: mongo:3.6.0
  volumes:
   - /data/mongodb/db:/data/db
  ports:
   - "27017:27017"

 api:
  build: .
  command: node ./bin/www
  volumes:
   - api-img:/CSCFUTSAL/public/plantillas
  ports:
   - "80:80"
  links:
   - mongo

volumes:
  api-img:
    driver: local
```

I dont know how to repair this without losing the data stored.

Answer (score 0):

The answers lie within the error.

- Just go to the location where "mongod.exe" is installed.
  **Note:** For Windows OS, it is generally installed at `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin`.
- Open cmd at the same location.
- Run the following command: `mongod.exe --repair`

This command will do the needful reparations.

After that just run `mongod.exe` from the same location.

The above solution worked for me. I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you're running this inside Docker you'll need to run the `mongod --repair` command in a container. Make sure you have a back up of the data you're going to repair and then run something like:

```
docker container run --rm -v /data/mongodb/db:/data/db mongo:3.6.0 mongod --repair
```

That's assuming that your local data is at `/data/mongodb/db`, which your Docker compose file suggests.

Comment: Nowadays, mongodb got a new version, so the command would be: `docker container run --rm -v /root/it_has_alternatives/configs/mongodb_data:/data/db mongo:6.0.4-jammy mongod --repair`