# Dockerized Mongodb container exits with code 14

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am building a react app using docker. After dockerizing the app, whenever i use docker-compose client and server run successfully but db part gives an error. Below is my docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
services:
  client:
    build: ./client
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
  
  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      MONGO_URI: mongodb://db/simpleoj
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
  
  db:
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    volumes:
      - simpleoj:/data/db

volumes:
  simpleoj:
```

When I run docker-compose up mongodb container exits with code 14. Below is the error message

```
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:36.784+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.059+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=5ae24bd2b007
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.059+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.28
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.059+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: af1a9dc12adcfa83cc19571cb3faba26eeddac92
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.059+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.059+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.059+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.059+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.059+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.059+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.059+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.059+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true } }
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.124+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.124+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.124+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.124+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.124+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.124+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:37.124+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=2427M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:38.689+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1658252738:689652][1:0x7f9a85504a80], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 6/256 to 7/256
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:38.691+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1658252738:691694][1:0x7f9a85504a80], txn-recover: Recovering log 6 through 7
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:39.152+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1658252739:152422][1:0x7f9a85504a80], txn-recover: Recovering log 7 through 7
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:39.210+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1658252739:210419][1:0x7f9a85504a80], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:40.897+0000 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:40.899+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Starting to check the table logging settings for existing WiredTiger tables
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:41.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:41.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:41.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:41.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:41.256+0000 F STORAGE  [initandlisten] Unable to start up mongod due to missing featureCompatibilityVersion document.
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:41.256+0000 F STORAGE  [initandlisten] Please run with --repair to restore the document.
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:41.256+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40652 at src/mongo/db/repair_database_and_check_version.cpp 608
db_1      | 2022-07-19T17:45:41.256+0000 F -        [initandlisten] \n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n
simpleoj_db_1 exited with code 14
```

If I run the container using

```
docker run -p 27018:27017 -v simpleoj:/data/app mongo:4.0-xenial
```

then it works perfectly. When I use docker-compose, it gives an error.
How do I solve this error?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174994/unable-to-start-up-mongod-due-to-missing-featurecompatibilityversion-document-d